# Jasperserver URL - PHP

Tags: php, soap, jasperserver, vtiger

When I log in on Jasperserver, everything is ok. I can execute all the reports with parameters.

But when I log in through PHP with that URL:

```
$url="https://company.domain.com:8443/jasperserver/home.html?j_username=".$login_user_name."&j_password=".$accesskey;
```

I can't execute reports with parameters (date) every time I have the message:

> enter valid date format...

Comment: You're most likely missing a POST variable?

Comment: No? It's because suddenly my date format changes...
when i normally log in to jasperserver the format = yyyy-mm-dd
But when I login through php the dateformat is dd/mm/yyyy
How can I fix that?